# Do opponents see your alternate hero?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone you can use a few different alternate heroes for yourself, which are basically just skins and provide no benefit other than a cosmetic change. I bought the Magni Bronzebeard warrior hero since I dislike Garrosh.

I haven't been playing Hearthstone particularly long; however, I've been playing fairly regularly the past few weeks, and after buying and using this skin I realize that I've never actually seen any of my opponents using an alternate hero.

I know from reading different sites that the price of alternate heroes was a bitter subject for Hearthstone players. I think that surely I should have run into someone else using one of the currently available alternate hero skins by now, though. I haven't even seen anyone using the Lady Liadrin hero, who is completely free to obtain.

This has led me to wonder: **Can opponents even *see* your alternate hero skin**?

Comment: I haven't played Hearthstone in a very long time but I think that they can see your alternate heroes. Isn't the whole point of alternate heroes showing off your preferred style?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would think. But I haven't seen anyone else use one yet, which seems strange to me. If they really are that unpopular and very few people are actually using them, it's fine. But if I spent $10 on something no one else can see, I'll be upset.

Comment: I hear ya. If it costs that much then I believe it's almost certain they can see it. Let's see if a Hearthstone expert can clarify the matter :).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes, other players see your skin instead of the default hero for your class!

They also hear the different voiceovers and emotes of course, that's what skins are for.

I can't really confirm your experience to be honest, I personally see them a lot when playing ladder. When the skins came out it was actually very rare to see a regular hero instead of the alternate one. ^^

I have to mention that I usually play on the higher ranks, so my opponents are playing for a longer time as well, increasing the chance that someone there bought a skin. In the lower ranks there are a lot of new players which probably don't want to pay money for cosmetic stuff when they can spend the money on card packs. However, this is just a wild guess but I think it goes to the right direction.

Comment: I play around rank 18-20 and see the alternate heroes quite often

Comment: Lady Liadrin (the paladin skin) [can be obtained for free by simply reaching level 20 on World of Warcraft.](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Lady_Liadrin#How_to_get), since starter World of Warcraft accounts are free and can be played up to level 20, thus making it more likely that someone play as her over Magni or Medivh.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I finally saw an opponent using Khadgar today. It totally figures that I finally see someone using a skin the same day after I decide to finally ask about it..

Comment: I play around rank ~10 each season when active and I can share OP's experience. I have to say I more often encoutner elgendary cardbacks or golden heroe variants then alternate heroes.

Comment: @LucasSant'Anna It's likely as long as paladin is okay in the meta :D

Comment: I want to point out, that some cards have special sounds when played against alternate hero (e.g. the Bronzebeard brothers)